# Why do I see "Not authorized to access this subscription" in SNS Console?

Tags: amazon-sns

I created an SNS topic in AWS.  A third party subscribed their SQS to it.  I'd like to now add a filter to the subscription from the console.  But, when I click on their subscription I am taken to the details page where I see a red banner at the top of the page stating:

> Couldn't retrieve subscription attributes. Error code:
>   AuthorizationError - Error message: Not authorized to access this
>   subscription

Given that it is my SNS topic, why can't I edit the filters on this page?

Would a better way to do this be to have the subscriber delete their subscription and then I create it on my side?  Would that then give me permission to add filters?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: The third party created the subscription in my account resulting in my not being able to access it.  I had the third party delete the subscription and I then created the subscription on my side.  That solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you Todd for replying. The same thing happened with me. The subscription was created from another AWS account which makes that account as the owner of the subscription. This is also the reason I cannot access it from my AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

SNS subscription can be managed by the account who created it. If you create it then you can manage if foreign account creates it then they manage it.

In mentioned case third party who owns SQS need to go to SNS view of an AWS console in their AWS account to manage subscription filter. Read more [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sns-sqs-authorization-error)